# Display an image in a userform at native resolution, and label that image

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to display an image in a userform, at its native resolution.

I'm using 64 bit Excel to do this.

I have about 300 images, and they are all standard sizes, (640x480 - 1024x768 etc.) I want to display one of these images at its native resolution, so I have done this:

```
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Image_Load)
Image1.PictureAlignment = fmPictureAlignmentTopLeft
Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeClip
```

(Where `Image1` is an `MSForms.Image` object)

I need to label these images with about 5-30 labels (different for each image), and I know exactly which pixels I want to position the top left of each of these labels on, but you can't do anything with pixels in VBA it would seem.

So, I have tried, (Where `px` is the input pixel value):

`Px / ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(1)` - This returns a value of 29.63 for an input of 800 pixels, which is pretty much 40 pixels. It returns 2.26 for an input of 600 using the `Y` function (This is about 3 pixels).

`Private Declare Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "user32" Alias "GetSystemMetrics"` ... This goes on for some time. I can't use this with 64-bit office.

`TwipsPerPixelX()` This function only exits in 32-bit office.

`Application.PixelsToPoints` This function only exists in every other office application. Not Excel.

So, to summarise, how do I place labels at pixel coordinates on a form image?

Any ideas you guys have would be a massive help.

Comment: `fmPictureAlignmentTopLeft` does allign picture to top left, so there's something else wrong with your code.

Comment: Yep, during testing I had somehow managed to set the picture property of the form background, so that was the red herring there. I'll edit the question. Can you help with the pixel positioning part?

Comment: That's not true that you cannot use API functions in 64-bit office. [Here](http://officeoneonline.com/vba/positioning_using_pixels.html) is a nice example on how to convert pixels to points. To make it work in 64-bit Office change API functions declarations to `Private Declare PtrSafe Function` and return value of `GetDC` to `LongPtr`